# Decrementing rcx in assembly yielding 0x00007fff988c63c7 instead of 1 in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to make a simple assembly program that prints "Hey dude!" 3 times to the screen using the C puts() function. My code is as follows:

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; This is an macOS console program that writes "Hey dude!" on one line and then exits.
; It uses puts from the C library.  To assemble and run:
;
;   To compile:
;     nasm -fmacho64 Program.asm && gcc Program.o -o Program && ./Program
;
;   Line by line:
;     nasm -fmacho64 Program.asm # Generate Program.o
;     gcc Program.o -o Program   # Compile Program.o into an executable
;     ./Program                  # Execute program
;   
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        global    _main
        extern    _puts


        section   .text
_main:    
        ; Set up stack frame
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp,    rsp
        sub     rsp,    24

        push    rbx                     ; Call stack must be aligned, 
                                        ; not doing this leads to segmentation fault

        xor     rcx,    rcx

        mov     rcx,    3                   ; Loop 3 times
While:
        cmp     rcx,    0
        je      EndLoop
        dec     rcx
RCXDEC:
        lea     rdi, [rel message]      ; First argument is address of message
        call    _puts                   ; puts(message)
        jmp     While
EndLoop:
        pop     rbx                     ; Fix up stack before returning

        xor     rax,    rax             ; Return 0
        leave
        ret

        section   .data
message:  db        "Hey dude!", 0        ; C strings need a zero byte at the end
```

However, it prints "Hey dude!" infinitely to the screen. Using lldb to debug it, I think I have found the source of the problem. Setting a breakpoint at RCXDEC, I allowed the loop to execute once. Reading the value of rcx, I see it is:

```
0x0000000000000002
```

As it should be, since rcx was 3 but was decremented once. The problem appears to occur on the second iteration of the loop. rcx is decremented again, but lldb says its value is now

```
0x00007fff988c63c7  libsystem_pthread.dylib`_thread + 71
```

Which would explain my problems. Letting the code run through more times does not change the value of rcx, even though it should be decrementing.

How do I fix this? All I want it to do is print 3 times.

My architecture is x86, and as you can see I am using NASM and GCC to compile.

I'm new to assembly and to stack overflow, so please tell me what I did wrong before down voting. Any and all help will be much appreciated.

Comment: rcx is call-clobbered, and you call `_puts` inside your loop.  Use a different register for your loop counter; one that's call-preserved in the x86-64 System V calling convention.

Comment: @PeterCordes Could you elaborate further?

Comment: See the linked duplicate.  Linux and OS X use the same function-calling convention.